# I program the calculator, I met the setting function problem

Tags: python, calculator

I implemented shape of calculator.
I want the command of Button, but I met the function error.
Please help the function setting.
If I click the button, then want to show the text of button.

This is my code.

```
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("My Calculator")

#버튼 입력 함수 설정
def click():
    display.insert(0, button_array[i,j])

#계산 결과 표시할 위치
display = Entry(window, width=33, bg="yellow")
display.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5)

#버튼 리스트로 만든 뒤 array 형태로 변경
button_list = [
        '7','8','9','/','C',
        '4','5','6','*',' ',
        '1','2','3','-',' ',
        '0','.','=','+',' ']
button_array = np.array(button_list).reshape(4,5)

for i in range(4):
    for j in range(5):
        b = Button(window, text=button_array[i,j], width=5, command=click)
        b.grid(row=i+1, column=j)


window.mainloop()
```

Please help me and sorry about I'm not good at english.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the actual error (the stacktrace will also be helpful).

Comment: I am in the development stage of calculator. I want to set if I click the button, that number or operation will be showen in display(Entry line). How to set the function of buttons? Please give me a hint

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set a StringVar object, as set it as the display's "textvariable" attribute (when creating the display).
Then on each change of the text, use the set method of the StringVar to change the text.

Try looking at [this example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-simple-gui-calculator-using-tkinter/)

Good Luck,
Dan